# How to escape the underscore in SQLite query with "where" clause

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would like to query the following database:

```
sqlite> select * from queue;
739cdbff68914b688509372af85ac05e|31967522_13|rendering
810c69dc4d68425f83c82aa1ac0a625e||waiting_train
af6f5d0c5cb2472fb311ccf6b738dacd|31967524_2|rendering
cf0164f51da64986a4ced63301aa1d85|31967522_3|training
ef07bb25da94472f87460768ea0b8f7d|31967522_16|rendering
testuidaxc|31967523|training
```

Querying with `job=31967523` is working:

```
sqlite> select * from queue where job='31967523';
testuidaxc|31967523|training
```

However, for jobs with an underscore it is not working no matter how I tried:

```
sqlite> select * from queue where job='31967522_3';
sqlite> select * from queue where job='31967522[_]3';
sqlite> select * from queue where job=31967522[_]3;
Error: near "[_]": syntax error
sqlite> select * from queue where job='31967522[_]3';
```

All returned nothing or error. It seems that the underscore is causing the problem, but how should I escape it? Thanks.

Comment: All of your `select` queries which have a string literal on the RHS should at least be running.  I think you intended to use `LIKE`, but for some reason did not post those query attempts.

Answer (score 18):

I presume that instead of the following select query:

```
SELECT * FROM queue WHERE job = '31967522_3';
```

you really intended to write this query:

```
SELECT * FROM queue WHERE job LIKE '%31967522_3%';
```

Literal underscore when used with equals should have no problem.  When using `LIKE`, we may escape the underscore:

```
SELECT * FROM queue WHERE job LIKE '%31967522\_3%' ESCAPE '\';
```

The above query would match any record whose `job` contained the literal string `31967522_3`.

From the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) it seems that `ESCAPE` is always required when intending to use a certain character as an escape character for `LIKE`.  That is, there does not seem to be a default escape character.

Comment: For future viewer, notice the last part of this answer: you HAVE TO use `ESCAPE '\';`

Comment: NOTE, the escape is relative to the LIKE operator: you need an additional `ESCAPE '\'` for each like: `WHERE name LIKE 'asd\_%' ESCAPE '\' OR name LIKE 'dsa\_%` ESCAPE '\'`

Answer (score 0):

```
 select * from queue where job='31967522'||CHR(95)||'3';
 select * from queue where job='31967522'||CHR(95)||'3';
 select * from queue where job=31967522'||CHR(95)||'3';
 select * from queue where job='31967522'||CHR(95)||'3';
 select * from queue where job='31967522'||'_'||'3';
 select * from queue where job='31967522'||'_'||'3';
 select * from queue where job=31967522'||'_'||'3';
 select * from queue where job='31967522'||'_'||'3';
```